# Replacing entire column name with sub or gsub

Tags: r, rename, gsub

Hello I am trying to replace column names if a column contains a specific character. I am trying to use the `gsub()` function. This function however just replaces the string, I want them to replace the column name. From my df wide_data I want to replace the column name to "Spot_Rate" for the column name that contains "NominalYieldCurve.SpotRate":

```
    names(wide_data) <- gsub("NominalYieldCurve.SpotRate", "Spot_Rate", names(wide_data))
    names(wide_data) <- gsub("CreditModel.SpotSpread", "Spot_Spread", names(wide_data))
```

The original column name is `Nominal.YieldCurve.SpotRate(Govt,10,5)` and after gsub it is  `Spot_Rate(Govt,10,5)`. I Need it to be just `Spot_Rate`.  `dplyr rename()` seems not appropriate for this and changing column names by index is not suitable for my use case. Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a `tidyverse` solution using `rename_with` and the selection helper, `starts_with`.

```
library(tidyverse)

wide_data <- data.frame(
  `NominalYieldCurve.SpotRate(Govt,10,5)` = 1,
  CreditModel.SpotSpread123 = 1
)

wide_data %>%
  rename_with(~"Spot_Rate", .cols = starts_with("NominalYieldCurve.SpotRate")) %>%
  rename_with(~"Spot_Spread", .cols = starts_with("CreditModel.SpotSpread"))
#>   Spot_Rate Spot_Spread
#> 1         1           1
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `grepl` here:

```r
names(wide_data) <- ifelse(grepl("NominalYieldCurve.SpotRate", names(wide_data), fixed=TRUE),
                           "SpotRate", names(wide_data))
names(wide_data) <- ifelse(grepl("CreditModel.SpotSpread", names(wide_data), fixed=TRUE),
                           "SpotSpread", names(wide_data))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this using base R:

```
> names(wide_data)
[1] "NominalYieldCurve.SpotRate" "CreditModel.SpotSpread"
> names(wide_data)[names(wide_data) == 'NominalYieldCurve.SpotRate'] <- 'Spot_Rate'
> names(wide_data)[names(wide_data) == 'CreditModel.SpotSpread'] <- 'Spot_Spread'
> names(wide_data)
[1] "Spot_Rate"   "Spot_Spread"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions with `gsub()` to replace not only `Nominal.YieldCurve.SpotRate`, but also anything before or after it in the column name:

```
names(wide_data) <- gsub("^.*Nominal[.]YieldCurve[.]SpotRate.*$", "Spot_Rate", names(wide_data))
names(wide_data) <- gsub("^.*CreditModel[.]SpotSpread.*$", "Spot_Spread", names(wide_data))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `\\.` to represent a literal `.` for any regular expression pattern in R. Also, you have to also capture other characters in the name if you want to replace them altogether. Try this

```
names(wide_data) <- gsub(".*Nominal\\.YieldCurve\\.SpotRate.*", "Spot_Rate", names(wide_data))
names(wide_data) <- gsub("*CreditModel\\.SpotSpread.*", "Spot_Spread", names(wide_data))
```